# Chart control for Windows 8 metro style Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Do we have any chart control available in windows 8 metro style.?
In WP7(.Net ver 4.0) we have Windows.Form.DataVisualization.dll to deal with chart control. This dll is also come with .Net for metro style apps(Net ver 4.5).But while referencing this dll from (.Net ver 4.5 folder) its giving 2 build error as below....

Error 8 Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Windows.Forms.dll' E:\MyFolfer\MetroApp\ChartApp\ChartApp.csproj

Error 9 Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. ChartApp

Any idea...

Note:
Non-paid options are prefered.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do winforms in WinRT. It is a new UI and API.

Supposedly Telerik is working on a chart component.

Comment: But Telerik is paid control.don't we get any free controls for this ?

Comment: Not yet, but you can set up some google alerts.

Comment: Or you could just sign up for the preview http://www.telerik.com/early-windows-8-adopters.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can [build Metro Style Applications using HTML5-Javacript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx), so you could use the GPL project [dhtmlx](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/index.shtml)

From the home-page:

> dhtmlxChart is a pure JavaScript charting library for generating Ajax
>   charts on a web page

Answer (score 1):

You need an internet connection for it, but I've had some luck with Google's Image Chart API: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/

The API has been deprecated and will no longer work after April 2015, but by that time I assume that there will be a number of other vendors to choose from.